# How can I change my page HTML in 3 Blocks?

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-4, styles

Hey I want to style my HTML like this:

[image: HTML look like this]
I currently have this:

```html
<app-list-employees></app-list-employees>
<app-book-employee></app-book-employee>
<app-calendar-books></app-calendar-books>
```

I also use Bootstrap if you have a solution with it. My `styles.scss` file is empty.

***EDIT:***
I have some DIV around the components like:

```
<div class="row text-center">
```

in the listEmployees Component or

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
```

and

```
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="deviceForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

in the CreateEmployee Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize Bootstrap that you are using.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <app-list-employees></app-list-employees>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div><app-book-employee></app-book-employee></div>
    <div><app-calendar-books></app-calendar-books></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    Employee List
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div>Book Employee</div>
    <div>Calendar Books</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to have equal heights for the row then use `.row-eq-height`

Comment: That didn't work for me. Now the Components goes vertical down the page like before.

Comment: @JustHeadache Check the demo snippet that works with Bootstrap.

Comment: I am sure that I am using Bootstrap because I styled the table in     <app-list-employees></app-list-employees> and the inputfields in     <app-book-employee></app-book-employee> with it.

Comment: That one worked but can u maybe explain me why did it work? I have bootstrap installed but it didn't work before

Comment: @JustHeadache not sure what went wrong at first point. Maybe, I surround it with `div` now. I am glad it help finally. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Angular Flex Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) like this :

```
<div>
    <div fxFlex="row">
        <div style="background:red" fxFlex="column">List employees</div>
        <div fxFlex="column">
            <div style="background:yellow">Book Employee</div>
            <div style="background:green">Calendar Book</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Same error like before: It shows up vertical down the page for me...  [link]:https://i.imgur.com/Ar9jYMe.png

Comment: Do you have a container around these components ? Could you show more code ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <app-list-employees></app-list-employees>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <app-book-employee></app-book-employee>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <app-calendar-books></app-calendar-books>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```